# Proper way to use .populate() mongodb Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to attach the full user model to each comment in my comments section. Since mongodb doesn't have joins I have been trying to figure out how to use .populate() to add the user object from the controller. As I understand it, to use the populate function there are only two things you must do.

1. Define a ref in the model.
2. Call .populate() on the name of the field which has a ref defined.

I have defined the ref in the model to the 'User' model:

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: { type: String, ref: 'User' },
  description: String,
  commentID: String,
  hasParent: String,
  parentComment: String,
  timestamp: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});
```

Then I am trying to add the user model to the author field in the comment object:

```
Comment
  .find() 
  .populate('author')
  .exec(function (err, comments) {
    console.log(comments);
  });
```

Is there a step that I am missing? I was hoping to see all the comments with the full user object in the author field of each comment.

Comment: Your `populate()` does not seem to be the problem. I don't knwo about the structure of your User model, but you should reference the `_id` of the User. `author: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was deleting the comments collection from mongodb. Starting fresh it works as expected. If anyone runs into a similar problem try deleting the collection of objects that were created before you had added a ref to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider making following changes.

```
author: { type: String, ref: 'User' };
authot: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'};
```

Comment: Did you mean `authot`? Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.